# NotWritablePropertyException with Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

There must be some subtlety in the way my class variables are being looked at by Spring. I've reviewed the associated files and am unable to spot where I am being inconsistent with *something*. Can you help me find what it is?

The error I'm getting is:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'memberVariableClass' of bean class [ClassName]: Bean property 'memberVariableClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Here's the top-level bean, ClassName.java:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class ClassName {

    private MemberVariableClass memberService;
    // private EditorService spanishEditorService;

    public ClassName() {

    }

    // public ClassName(MemberVariableClass memberVariableClassArgument) {
    //  this.memberService = memberVariableClassArgument;
    // }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    public void setMemberService(MemberVariableClass memberService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }
}
```

Here's the MemberVariableClass interface followed by its implementation:

```
/* 
 * The old EditorService. 
 * Probably be best if name was MemberVariableClassInterface... for now.
 */
public interface MemberVariableClass {

    public String dummyMethod();

    public String getAttribute();

}

public class MemberVariableClassImpl implements MemberVariableClass {

    String attribute = "value";

    public String dummyMethod() {
        return "Hi I'm a dummy method.";
    }

    public String getAttribute() {
        return this.attribute;
    }
}
```

and finally, here's the servletContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean name="className" class="ClassName">
        <property name="memberService" ref="memberVariableClassImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="memberVariableClassImpl" class="MemberVariableClassImpl" />    
</beans>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're actually running? The error would suggest your XML actually reads `<property name="memberVariableClass" ref="memberVariableClassImpl" />`. This would cause the `NotWritablePropertyException` as Spring uses JavaBeans conventions to match property getters/setters. Yet another reason to use JavaConfig, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to avoid the @Autowired annotation, but you do want to use annotation-style controllers. I'd encourage you, to using @Autowired at least for controllers, It makes easier to code and to read, and it shouldn't lead to any awkward, confusing interdependencies.

```
@Controller
public class ClassName {

    @Autowired
    private MemberVariableClass memberService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

servletContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean name="memberVariableClassImpl" class="com.package.MemberVariableClassImpl" />    
</beans>
```

remember to include the `context:component-scan` as well in your xml